# syntax error near unexpected token `(' OR no proper execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to do something on X dirs but not on Y ones via the terminal.
When I do

```
cd /mnt/dir/ && 
for i in !(dira|dirb|dird)/; do echo "$i"; done && 
cd y/ && for i in !(dirz)/; do echo "$i"; done
```

on the terminal everthing is fine but when I try to put it on a .sh file and execute it I get the `syntax error near unexpected token (`  or, if I escape `(` and `|` I just get the `for` part as output (eg: `!(dira|dirb|dird)/`)

How can I fix this so I can get it working on a .sh file or even on an alias inside my .bashaliases file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an extended globbing pattern. For this to work in your script, make sure that you are

1. using `bash` to execute the script, and
2. enable the `extglob` shell option in the script.

You may enable the `extglob` shell option with the command

```
shopt -s extglob
```

in the script source.

Comment: I think I am. The `.sh` file is executable in a floder along other files that work properly. I've tried using `./file.sh` and `/bin/bash/ .file.sh`  Also the output of `shopt extglob` is `extglob on`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: @AdrianSkar The `extglob` shell option is not enable by default in `bash` shell scripts (even if it's enabled in the shell that invokes the script).  You will have to explicitly enable it inside the script.

Comment: I'm such a noob regarding bash. Ok my file now looks like this `shopt -s extglob &&
cd /mnt/dir/ && 
for i in !(dira|dirb|dird)/; do echo "$i"; done && 
cd y/ && for i in !(dirz)/; do echo "$i"; done` but I get the syntax error.

Comment: @AdrianSkar No worries. Put the `shopt` command on a line by itself. On the next line, do your `cd` etc.

Comment: Ok, this is what it looks like: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/KQmzN4d.png) The output is `syntax error near unexpected token (`. If I use `sudo ./file.sh` the output is  ` Syntax error: ( unexpected`

Comment: @AdrianSkar Sorry, I should have been more clear. Don't try to string the `shopt` command onto the `cd` with `&&` in-between. First have the `shopt` command, then have the `cd` etc. on the next line. No `&&` in-between.  Just `shopt -s extglob` on a line by itself.

Comment: Yay! You are great! It worked perfectly. I'll take a deeper look into the extended globbing patterns so I can understand that better. Tyvm!